# How to communicate between LocalSocket in java and unix socket in c++?

Tags: android, localsocket

I create socket client in Android Java code:

```
LocalSocket sock = new LocalSocket(LocalSocket.SOCKET_DGRAM);
sock.connect(new LocalSocketAddress(path));
```

my server is create in JNI.
when i install to my device, sock.connect often throw connection refused exception.